# proper usage of MySQL docker container while integrating with java application

Tags: java, mysql, docker

Currently I am trying to implement some eCommerce functionality in java. And I would like to pull data from MySQL and utilize the same. So for this purpose I wanted to use MySQL docker container for the first time. And in my Linux server(host) I have installed docker and created a custom MySQL container with Image. so here the question is how to use this container in my local computer. And is this the way we suppose to access MySQL from local ?? or we create a different container for our local server by installing docker from the image? And how to access this container from host server (I mean the endpoint). Could someone please elaborate the clear use case of MySQL docker container. if you have any questions for my query please ask so that I will reply in comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , this will give you an idea how to ask a good question here.
I havent use `MySQL` docker image, as I heard, its good for testing purposes. But for production, you better to do a good RnD about it.

Comment: Hey @SachithMuhandiram Thank for the reply. I didn't understand why u tagged that link for asking good question. I believe this question would be good enough to get some basic knowledge on MySQL with docker from the other colleagues.  let me know if u need some more understanding on the question.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram is right : What you are asking here is near by asking a complete tutorial on Docker...please read the "How to ask section" and you will mainly see what to ask and how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion: 
first I have used MySQL official image and I have created a docker-compose.YAML file for creating a new container.
following commands is an example for you.

just pay attention to create a network first and put your MySQL and java containers at the same network.

```
docker network create mysql-network
```

then create a yaml file and put these commands:

```
    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: mysql
      restart: always
      networks:
        #- mysql_network
        - mysql_newtwork
      command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456789
          MYSQL_DATABASE: database
          MYSQL_USER: user_db
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      volumes:
        - /home/mysql_backup/storage/mysql-data/dev:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: You do not need the `container_name:` or `networks:` options; [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the features Compose creates for you by default.  If you're using Compose to manage a network then you don't need to separately `docker network create` it.